# My website won't load

Tags: internet, website

I'm a web developer. I'm building a website right now, and this project requires lot of changes to be done on the server. To check the changes, I'll load the page every few seconds.However, in the past few days my website no longer loads.

A special behavior I noticed is that my website opens for a few minutes after I switch on my modem, then it stops. When I restart my modem it works again for another few minutes, then I need to restart again.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The description is so confused that I really can't tell what you are asking.  Sorry.

Comment: Please edit the question and rewrite it stating which platform (windows 7 64?), which server (IIS 7.5?), which client (Chrome 13.0.782.220?), which Modem (megafoo 500?), what you did, what exactly happened (exact error messages) and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your frequent refreshing triggers a firewall that blocks you for DDoS protection reasons. When you restart your modem you get a new IP, which enables you to access the server again until you get blocked.